# text underline for full text

Tags: html, css

I want to create a line below a multi-line block of text up to the length of the longest line of text in that block. I want to achieve something like that:

```
`Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum,
 Lorem Ipsum
 =========================----------------`
```

Example what I did so far
http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/82/

Comment: You declared 300px width on parent element. How can it be "FULL WIDTH" if you declared `300px`

Comment: why not just use `text-decoration:underline`?

Comment: @LaraBelle by full width I mean full text:)

Comment: @Tijmen I can't use it, beacuse text-decoration underline first line too:(

Comment: @K.A.T. in that case you can apply `text-decoration` to a separate class, and then apply that class to the second line only using `span`. Alternatively, you might consider adding a `border-bottom`, but that would be full with, not text width.

Comment: @Tijmen I can't because I don't know what will be second line (responsive view) and It's a users's wysiwyg:(

Comment: looking at your fiddle, it seems you already have what you are asking for. Can you please elaborate more on question.

Comment: @DeepakYadav I want this black border be up to longest line of the text

Comment: @K.A.T. the way you gave `red-border` similarly declare the `black-border`. I'm still confused. Check the below shared answer by Mayardesign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to using jQuery you could...

1. Get the width of the `span`
2. Append a `hr` of that width
3. Style the `hr` as needed

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/5yL9kLfq/3/)

```js
$(function() {

  $('span').each(function() {
    var w = $(this).width();
    var l = $('<hr />');

    l.css("width", w);
    $(this).append(l);
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

hr {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, </span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, </span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<div style="display:block;width:300px;">
  <span>Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, LoremhkjhkasdasdffasfasfasfjhjkIpsum, </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm open for JS and jQuery solutions, but I prefer try to do something in pure CSS, and then, when it's not possible, use JS solutions, so I'm gratefully for that solution

Comment: it's not responsive though

Answer (score 1):

This achieves your goal as stated:

```css
p {
 display: inline-block;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
  <p>Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work if there are no explicit breaks (<br/>) in the text - the line will extend to the full width of the parent container.

Comment: Thank, good idea, but this work only if u have a <br/> tag, If u remove it It doesn't work. Fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/83/

Comment: I assumed there were line breaks, otherwise why would you not simply underline the p tag? I am not sure anyone understands your question :(

Comment: text-decoration:underline will underline every line in "p" tag, I want underline only last one, but with length of the longest line in this tag

Comment: I didn't say to use text-decoration, I meant p {border-bottom: 2px solid black}

Comment: I tried it in my last fiddle, but It dont' work properly (width isn't as long as longest text, but loger)